# Monitoring Listener detects only one beacon

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, estimote

I have 3 Estimote Beacons (Div Kit). In my Android app I'm trying to change 3 TextViews to show each beacon's major and minor. I've changed the beacons settings to advertise signal every 1ms which is the shortest period of time.

The problem is that my `BeaconManager` object is detecting only one beacon and it takes a while to do that.

Here is my code

App.java

```
public class App extends Application {

    public static BeaconManager mBeaconManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mBeaconManager = new BeaconManager(getApplicationContext());
        mBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1), 0);

        mBeaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceReady() {
                mBeaconManager.startMonitoring(new Region(
                        "monitored region",
                        UUID.fromString("B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"),
                        null, null));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        final TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        final TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);

        App.mBeaconManager.setMonitoringListener(new BeaconManager.MonitoringListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEnteredRegion(Region region, List<Beacon> list) {
                tv.setText(list.get(0).getMajor() + " : " + list.get(0).getMinor());
                if (list.size() > 1) {
                    tv2.setText(list.get(1).getMajor() + " : " + list.get(1).getMinor());
                }
                if (list.size() > 2) {
                    tv3.setText(list.get(2).getMajor() + " : " + list.get(2).getMinor());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onExitedRegion(Region region) {
                tv.setText("Exit");
            }
        });
    }
```

I know the code might be nonprofessional but it is only for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got a same problem 
but I resolve this problem

```
beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override            
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            Log.i("test", "Detected " + beacons.size());
            if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                beaconList.clear();
                for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
                    beacon.setHardwareEqualityEnforced(true);
                    beaconList.add(beacon);
                }
            }
```

I insert beacon.setHardwareEqualityEnforced(true);

Answer (score 0):

Try this after this your method.

```
mBeaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceReady() {
            mBeaconManager.startMonitoring(new Region(
                    "monitored region",
                    UUID.fromString("B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"),
                    null, null));
        }
});

// Apply this method mBeaconManager.setRangingListener

mBeaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {

    @Override
    public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, final List<Beacon> beaconList) {
        if (!beaconList.isEmpty()) {
        // You will find total list of beacon around of you.
            Log.e("Length of Beacon List - ", String.valueOf(beaconList.size()));
        }
    }
});
```